# unable to type more than a letter in formarray textbox

Tags: angular, validation, formarray

I have a form, inside the form.And when i click on add new text field after selection of dropdown with value "3", I'm calling a form array, where i get multiple textboxes.
Everything is working fine.
But i got an issue:

I want to add a new textfields only if the selected field is not empty.
That is, if "listItem" textbox is empty and when i click on "addnew textfield" it show an alert.
and similarly for all the textfields.

I'm unable to type more than a single letter in formarray fields.

Please help me fix the issues.
Thanks in advance.

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                   
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter term"
                          formControlName="name">   
                
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Id"
                        formControlName="id">   
           
                        
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" formControlName="type">                                     

                        <select class="Dropdown" formControlName="category">
                            <option value="undefined" selected disabled >Select Category</option>
                            <option  *ngFor="let list of test" [value]="list.id" >{{list.name}}</option>
                        </select> 


                    <ng-container *ngIf="showarray">
                                               
                          <input type="text" formControlName="listItem" class="form-control" placeholder="enter dropdownlist items"> 
                          <a (click)="addGroup()">Add New Textfield</a>

                    </ng-container>
                    
                     <span formArrayName="times" *ngFor="let time of addForm.controls.times?.value; let i = index;">                          
                      <span [formGroupName]="i">                         
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lists" placeholder="enter dropdown options">  

                      </span>
                     <a (click)="removeGroup(i)">Remove Textfield</a>
                     </span>                   
                     
                          <input type="Submit" class="savebtn" Value="Save" Style="width: 100px;"/>&nbsp;
 
                  </form>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  addForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  showarray: any;

  public dropdownitems = [{
    name: "A",
    id: 1
  },{
    name: "B",
    id: 2
  },{
    name: "C",
    id: 3   
  },{
    name: "D",
    id: 4    
  }]


 constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z# ]*')]] ,
      times: this.formBuilder.array([])
      }); 

  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.addForm.invalid) {
      alert ('Please fill up complete details');
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.addForm.value);   
}


value = this.formBuilder.group({
  lists: ['', Validators.required],
});


addGroup() {
  const val = this.formBuilder.group({
    lists: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  const form = this.addForm.get('times') as FormArray;
  form.push(val);
}

removeGroup(index) {
  const form = this.addForm.get('times') as FormArray;
  form.removeAt(index);
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is how you iterate over the formArray. You can **not use** `*ngFor="let time of addForm.controls.times?.value;`, you need create a getter with the formArray and iterate over the formArray.controls (never over the "value") else, each time you makes a change, Angular repaint the array and you loose the focus.

So, first create a function like

```
  get timesArray()
  {
    return this.addForm.get('times') as FormArray
  }
```

Then take attention to the tags

```
   <!--first a div (or ng-container if you can not add extra tags) with formArrayName-->
   <ng-container formArrayName="times">
   <!--then iterate over timesArray.controls and use [formGroupName]-->
     <span *ngFor="let time of timesArray.controls;let i=index"
             [formGroupName]="i">
         <!--after you use formControlName-->
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lists" 
                   placeholder="enter dropdown options">  
            <a (click)="removeGroup(i)">Remove Textfield</a>
        </span>
   </ng-container>
```

BTW: Well, you has a formArray of FormGroups, you can also choose to have a FormArray of FormControls. I know that this is not your form, but if only want to have an array of values instead an array of object the tags changes, see that in this case you don't use [formGroupName] and formControlName="list" else [formControlName]="i"

```
   <!--first a div (or ng-container if you can not add extra tags) with formArrayName-->
    <div formArrayName="times">
        <!--then iterate over timesArray.controls -->
        <span *ngFor="let time of timesArray.controls;let i=index">
         <!--after you use formControlName[i]-->
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i" 
                   placeholder="enter dropdown options">  
            <a (click)="removeGroup(i)">Remove Textfield</a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Well, in this case, the functions addGroup and removeGroup are simply

```
//see that we use the "getter" timesArray
addGroup() {
 this.timesArray.push(new FormControl());
}
removeGroup(index) {
 this.timesArray.removeAt(index)
}
```

You can check this [article of Netanel Basal](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a) about FormArrays

Comment: I don't know what is your aproach or your aim: You can has an unique FormGroup and when "save" add to an array the values of the FormGroup, has an array of FormGroups and when "save" add a new FormGroup or has a FormArray of FormGroups. You need ask you what do you need

Comment: you can ask about `this.timesArray.valid` or about `this.addForm.get('listItem').valid` or even about both `ìf (this.timesArray.valid && this.addForm.get('listItem').valid)`.NOTE: you can use a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArray of FormsGroup according your requeriments, I wrote about FormArray of FormControls because if only need and array of strings it's not necesary an array of objects

Comment: see your forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oatmjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, see that I change the .html to show the FormArray and that I add a "getter" timesArray